# Filter QTreeView to return nodes when matching with root OR child node

Tags: python-3.x, filtering, pyqt5, qtreeview

I have a QTreeVIew populated with data via a `QAbstractItemModel`, i can filter the view using `QSortFilterProxyModel.setFilterRegExp` but if my filter string doesnt match the root node, non of the matches among the child nodes are returned. In other words, the string I'm using to look for matches among the nodes, have to match the root nodes for anything to be returned.

What i would like to do is to have all nodes with their respective parents and childnodes to return to the QTreeView when there is a match. The tree below shows what result i would like to have returned to the QTreeView when i search for `cat`

```
Animals
   cats
Cats
   kittens
   cat
       cats
       mice
       lice
Cars
   fantasy cars
       Catmobile
```

When i search for cat now, all that is returned is

```
Cats
   cats
       cats
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use QSortFilterProxyModel.filterAcceptsRow for this.
In my app I do it like this:

```
class SortModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):

  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(SortModel, self).__init__(parent)

  def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
    # check if an item is currently accepted 
    accepted = super(SortModel, self).filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent)  

    if accepted:
        return True

    # if it is not accepted may be item parent could be accepted
    model = self.sourceModel()    
    # get item parent [In my app I use only two levels for items,
    # so you need to make a function out of this to make it work for n levels ]
    index = model.index(source_row, self.filterKeyColumn(), source_parent)
    has_parent = model.itemFromIndex(index).parent()
    # if there is a parent
    if has_parent:
        parent_index = self.mapFromSource(has_parent.index())
        # check if parent is accepted
        return super(SortModel, self).filterAcceptsRow(has_parent.row(), parent_index)

    return accepted
```

If you use Qt 5.10 disable recursive filtering or enable it only when needed:

```
def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
    accepted = super(SortModel, self).filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent)

    if self.isRecursiveFilteringEnabled():
        return accepted
    else:
        if accepted:
            return True
    ...
```